# Delta and Theta functions

Tags: proof-verification, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics

I have a function $\theta (x-x') $ which is zero when $x-x'$ is negative and one when $x-x'$ is positive. I am to prove, $$\delta (x-x') = d/dx [\theta(x-x')] $$

The following is my reasoning:

I consider the action of $\theta$ on an arbitrary function $f$ whose anti-derivative $F$ is finite at infinity.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \theta(x-x') f(x') dx'= \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(x') dx' = F(x) - F(-\infty) \tag{1}$$

Expanding the above integral by parts I get, $$\theta(x-x') F(x') \Biggr|_{-\infty}^{\infty} + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d/dx[\theta(x-x')] F(x') dx'\tag{2}$$ Since, $$d/dx[\theta(x-x')] = - d/dx'[\theta(x-x')]$$

The first term of (2) is just $-F(-\infty)$. On combining (1) and (2) we get, $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d/dx[\theta(x-x')] F(x') dx'\tag{3} = F(x)$$ Eqn.(3) is identical to the known, $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-x')F(x') dx'\tag{3} = F(x)$$ We therefore conclude, $$\delta (x-x') = d/dx [\theta(x-x')] $$

I would like to know if there is any flaw in the reasoning.

Comment: The value of $\theta$ at $0$ does not affect $\text{(1)}$. Lebesgue integral is not affected by modification of values of the integrand on a measure-zero set.

Comment: While I don't yet understand the Lesbegue Integral, I do see that taking $\theta(0)=1$ does not affect the fact that $\delta$ goes to infinity as $x'$ tends to $x$.

Comment: Lebesgue integral is a generalization of Riemann integral that is robust under various limiting operations. Even in Riemann integral, modifying the value of integrand at one point does not affect its value. :)

Comment: @SangchulLee oh yes! I was silly enough to not think about it. Hahaha! I appreciate your reply.

Comment: Glad it helped :) And of course, as soon as you have $\delta$ in your integrand it is no longer a usual integral and my comment above no longer applies. (In mathematics, it is understood as a pairing between distribution and its test function. This reduces to ordinary integral only when the distribution is itself a regular function.)

Comment: @SangchulLee I understand that since the delta function is not just another ordinary function. What I would eventually like to know is if there are any flaws in the reasoning above.

Comment: @SangchulLee I have edited the post by excluding the doubt regarding $\theta(0)$.